# Calculating Forward Vector Given Rotation in 3D

Tags: math, rotation, linear-algebra, euler-angles, vectormath

Given a Vector 3 of Euler Angles, how could one mathematically find the direction that object is facing.

In other words, how does Unity calculate the 'transform.forward' vector?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: The more correct way should be to convert the rotation to radians, then do what meowgoesthedog said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on *spherical polar coordinates*, noting the difference between conventional polar and Euler angles. But anyway the formula is `(cos(pitch)cos(yaw), cos(pitch)sin(yaw), sin(pitch))`. Note that the roll has no effect here.